# Using brackets as delimiters for matrix in TikZ-PGF Matrix Library

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, tikz-matrix

The TikZ-PGF manual is clear that for the matrix library, the delimiters are parentheses and braces:

> Delimiters are parentheses or braces
>   to the left and right of a formula or
>   a matrix.

I would like to use brackets as delimiters for a matrix of math nodes. I have tried `\left[` and `\right]` but they do not work.

Is there any way to get brackets as delimiters for a matrix of math nodes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use `{[}` as the argument for `left delimiter`, and similar for the right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter={[},right delimiter={]}]
{
a_8 & a_1 & a_6 \\
a_3 & a_5 & a_7 \\
a_4 & a_9 & a_2 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The matrix was copied directly from the `pgf` manual (section 38.3 Delimiters),  only the delimiters changed. The reason you have to put the braces there is, I suspect, that the delimiter specification is placed within a set of brackets, and you therefore have to separate the delimiter brackets from the brackets for the matrix options.

Answer (score 7):

Yes Torbjorn T. is right, there is a problem with the brackets. You need to hide the bracket in tex group `{...}` but another solution is to write `right delimiter=\rbrack,left delimiter= 
\lbrack`

Comment: Thanks, @Altermundus. It too works. In my file, I needed to have `[left delimiter=\lbrack, right delimiter=\rbrack ]`. Note the space after \rbrack.