# How to make a full equation with tikz?

Tags: matrices, tikz-styles, tikz-matrix

I am using this solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57411/long-dashes-for-denoting-omitted-columns-of-a-matrix) to make long dashes within a matrix, and it is working well. The code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

% possible to customize here the dash aspect
\newcommand{\mydash}{
\draw(0.3,0.5ex)--(-0.3,0.5ex);
}

\begin{document}
\[P=
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.5ex]
\matrix(m)[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=),ampersand replacement=\&]
{
\mydash \&   y_1 \&   \mydash   \\
\mydash \&   y_2+z_2 \&  \mydash    \\
\mydash \&   y_3 \&   \mydash \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\]

\end{document}
```

However, I am now sure how to start writing full blown equations with it. I have not had much luck. The above makes a nice matrix with lines along the rows.

1) What I want is something like P = X Y Z, where X, Y , and Z, are all shown with the lines along its rows as in the prior example given. I cannot seem to concatenate them for whatever reason though...

2) I would like the matrix brackets to also be square, and not curvy.

Comment: As for the matrix brackets, you may simply modify the left and right delimiter to `[`.

Comment: @kan The program does not compile if I change the brackets to [

Comment: I am just writing an answer. I realised I messed that up, I am sorry!

Comment: To use brackets you need to wrap them in braces:, see [Using brackets as delimiters for matrix in TikZ-PGF Matrix Library](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20254)/

Comment: Could you explain your question 1, a little more please?

Comment: @kan I have drawn it up [here](http://d.pr/i/XdzP).

Comment: @Mohammad An answer is following! Just a few minutes please!

Comment: @kan Thanks - a picture is worth a thousand words! :-)

Comment: @Mohammad Indeed!!

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: @MartinSchröder ... thank you? ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) The point to realise is that: everything is happening in a math mode. And, `tikzpicture` is is simply a new environment in the math mode. So, you are not writing equations in Tikz. You're using Tikz only to get the dashes right. An example will hopefully set this right for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

% possible to customize here the dash aspect
\newcommand{\mydash}{
\draw(0.3,0.5ex)--(-0.3,0.5ex);
}

\begin{document}
\[X=
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.5ex]
\matrix(m)[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter={[},right delimiter={]},ampersand replacement=\&]
{
\mydash \&   u_1 \&   \mydash \\
\mydash \&   u_2 \&   \mydash \\
\mydash \&   u_3 \&   \mydash \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.5ex]
\matrix(m)[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter={[},right delimiter={]},ampersand replacement=\&]
{
\mydash \&   b_1 \&  \mydash \\
\mydash \&   b_2 \&  \mydash \\
\mydash \&   b_3 \&  \mydash \\
\mydash \&   b_4 \&  \mydash \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{bmatrix}
\biggl| \\
c_1 \\
\biggl|
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

**Output.**

[image: Output Image]

2) For the second question about the shape of the enclosing braces, we need to appropriately modify the options: `left delimiter` and `right delimiter`. In this case, we set it to: `{[}` and `{]}` respectively.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Very, very, beautiful. Thank you very much. A follow up or two: Would it be hard to make this [modification](http://d.pr/i/dfIg). 2) Suppose on the first matrix, you want to populate it with say, 4 numbers like a normal matrix. Also, modification is straight forward? Thanks!!

Comment: @Mohammad (1) It is possible, if you don't insist that the braces are at the same level. (Even otherwise, it should, in principle, be possible, but, I am just not aware of a method.) Check this out: https://www.writelatex.com/138403qnzgnm.

Comment: (2) As I said, you're in a math mode!! So, at the place, where you'd like your matrix, simply `\begin{bmatrix}` and input your matrix!

Comment: Yes, for (1) I dont insist that they are at the same level. How would you modify that to do so? For (2), thanks - got it.

Comment: @Mohammad Oh, since you don't care about the level at which they are placed, the link to writelatex in that comment does what you need! In particular, it uses the construct `\underbrace{}_{}` from `amsmath`. So, you'd enclose an entire `tikzpicture` or `bmatrix` environment within the first braces and write the text you like underneath that in the second braces. You may please look at the link and ask if you get stuck. :)